# F# string index, type inference not working

Tags: f#, type-inference

Why does this work, but if I comment out the second line it does not? Is it because F# cannot infer msg is a string?

Line 3 = msg can be indexed `msg[]`, and msg is string `String.length msg`.

Is this one of those situations where it is better to specify the type? `let isQuestion (msg:string) = ...`

```
let isQuestion msg =
    let n = String.length msg //if I comment this line out the function no longer works
    msg[(String.length msg - 1)] = '?'
```

Comment: Side note: you can use builtin method to check whether string ends with something `let isQuestion (msg:string) = msg.EndsWith '?'`

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the reason here is that the 2nd line is what tells the compiler that `msg` is unambiguously a string.

It's more complicated than this, but at a high level you can think of F# type inference as working as such:

top -> down

left -> right

In pre-F# 6, you would need to use `msg.[...]` to index the string, and with that syntax the error message is more clear:

```
The operator 'expr.[idx]' has been used on an object of indeterminate type based on information prior to this program point.
Consider adding further type constraints
```

However, in F# 6 it is a warning because you could *technically* be trying to write `msg [expr] = '?'`, which would mean that `msg` is a function that takes a list as input and produces a `char`. Because of this ambiguity, the warning is emitted and you're asked to specify a type to clarify your intent. And because `msg` is not inferred to be a string, you see an error in the `expr` part of the indexing expression.